# RedirectToAction works in controller but does not update the view and URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller for Login/Register and related actions. Ever since I changed the view from the one I made with Html helpers to test, to the one that my UI designer provided with html, after login I'm not redirected to the index page.

At first I thought that the login form was not submitting but after inserting some Console debug codes I realized that in the controller I am being redirected to the Index action but the Index view is not being showed in my browser and the URL is not changing.
Some developers with the same problem said it was because of the AJAX buttons but I don't think my view has those as far as I know and I don't know how to make sure.

This is my AccountController Code and the actions in it. I removed redundant codes from it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Redirected To Index");
    return View(model);
}
public ActionResult Login()
{            
    Console.WriteLine("Entered Login Get Action");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entered Login Post Action");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Login Redirect Action");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

and this is the form in my Login View that is being submitted with redundant codes removed:

```
     <form class="cozy" method="post">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username)
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
     </form>
```

After submitting, "Redirected To Index" is printed in the console along with the previous lines, but I don't get redirected to the actual page.

Thanks in advance for spending time to answer to my problem.

Comment: Is the `Index` view inside the `Account` directory?

Comment: in case of your index not in same controller use  `return RedirectToAction("Index", "IndexController");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem was with some js scripts in the view, preventing the redirect. I removed them and the code started working properly again. then I added those js references again and now the code works.
I don't know why and how it didn't before but this was what I did that made it work again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missed `action` attribute on the form.

```
<form class="cozy" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Login","Account")">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username)
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

That will call `Login` action with post method when you hit submit button on your form.
َAs suggested in comments, You can use `Html.BeginForm` razor helper instead of pure html code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform", @class = "cozy", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username)
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Html.BeginForm` helper?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried your solution but I got the same result. When I go to /Account/index manually I'm logged in but from the login page I don't get redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `return View(model);` try to provide the full path of the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Redirected To Index");
    return View("add actual path of the view", model); 
    //For Example
    //return View("~/Views/Test/Login.cshtml", model); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the problem and I posted the answer here. It was just weird honestly :)